# .net mvc Foreign Key Relationships with Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am developing an Intranet application and have successfully integrated with Active Directory.

When we add a new customer I would like to assign a Customer Advisor from a dropdown list.

I am able to populate the dropdown list using the following

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN", "dc=domain,dc=org");
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "customerAdvisors");
ViewBag.Guid = new SelectList(group.Members, "Guid", "DisplayName");
```

I would like to then store the Guid of the selected user along with the Customer data in the database.

However, I am unsure of how to setup foreign key constraints in my Model as the table I am joining to is within Active Directory.

Do I need to create a separate Employee table within my DB and sync the required fields or is there a simplified way of doing this?

Comment: Can you handle loading all of the Advisors into memory and joining w/ LINQ or something to a List<Advisor>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done this but some quick research makes it look possible.

You could just save the Guid for your adviser on your Customer.  The AD Guid can go into the Guid data type.  [You should be able to query individual users by using this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383475.aspx):

UserPrincipal user = 
  UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, yourUsersGuidAsAString);

The down side is that every time you want your customer adviser's info (like their name or email address) you will have to do a separate query to AD.  Harder to use ORM.

In my application I have a different use case, but I have also integrated my application with AD.  The route that I took was to save this information in my own DB instead of hitting AD every time.  In large part because my architecture makes it hard to get to AD in the same way you can.  Also it's easier to use ORM (like entity framework in my case) to pull in the information that I want.  The downside to this is then you need to ensure that the information you have in your database is reasonably up to date with what's in AD.

You will have to make the judgement on which approach makes the most sense for your architecture/use case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Ben That was basically the solution I had, was just wondering if there was a better way to do it. How do you keep your data in sync. Do you have a script for that by any chance?

Comment: No unfortunately.  Like I said my use case and architecture is different.  Without getting into too many details my connection to AD is indirect.  I am using ADFS to do Federated Authentication for my users.  So every time my users log in I update their info based on the claims AD is sending me.  My web app has no direct access to my AD server.  For your case maybe you could set something up to periodically poll AD (like a windows service that is always running and has a timer thread that executes every 24 hours)